# WordPress: SELECT wp_users and all associated meta data from wp_metadata into one row per user record

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

This is how I've been able to extract all of the relavant data into a single row for each `user` record:

```
SELECT user_login, user_pass, user_email, user_registered,
meta1.meta_value AS billing_address_1,
meta2.meta_value as billing_address_2,
meta3.meta_value as billing_city,
meta4.meta_value as billing_first_name,
meta5.meta_value as billing_last_name,
meta5.meta_value as billing_postcode,
meta5.meta_value as billing_country,
meta5.meta_value as billing_state
FROM wp_users users,
wp_usermeta meta1,
wp_usermeta meta2,
wp_usermeta meta3,
wp_usermeta meta4,
wp_usermeta meta5,
wp_usermeta meta6,
wp_usermeta meta7,
wp_usermeta meta8
WHERE users.id = meta1.user_id
    AND meta1.meta_key = 'billing_address_1'
AND users.id = meta2.user_id
    AND meta2.meta_key = 'billing_address_2'
AND users.id = meta3.user_id
    AND meta3.meta_key = 'billing_city'
AND users.id = meta4.user_id
    AND meta4.meta_key = 'billing_first_name'
AND users.id = meta5.user_id
    AND meta5.meta_key = 'billing_last_name'
AND users.id = meta6.user_id
    AND meta6.meta_key = 'billing_postcode'
AND users.id = meta7.user_id
    AND meta7.meta_key = 'billing_country'
AND users.id = meta8.user_id
    AND meta8.meta_key = 'billing_state'
```

However, at this point (and I haven't even listed half of the meta data that needs to be extracted), phpMyAdmin is telling me that my `JOIN` is too big ...

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a user with all details then you can simply use [get_userdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) function as given below

```
$user_info = get_userdata(1); // 1 is user ID here (required)
echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
echo 'User level: ' . $user_info->user_level . "\n";
echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
// more...
```

If you want to get the details of currently logged in user then you can use [get_currentuserinfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) function

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
```

Comment: Well, I'm doing this within MySQL so that I can export the data.

Comment: You can export the data using this approach too and this is `WordPress`'s recommended way.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to export the data so that it's flat ... none of this `key / value` nonesense. Imagine each `post type` as it's own database table, containing columns that represent all of the `metadata`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_user_meta()` function. It will return all of the user meta information for a specific user. Call the function for each user, in a loop.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a view and running the select on that instead?